# BASH script call new script when needs keypress to return to prompt

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have few script that i am executing one by one to stop and start the server. A couple of scripts will wait for 'enter' key to be pressed to return to prompt.

How can i automate my entire restart process by adding all the steps into single shell script which includes these couple of interactive scripts ?

I couldn't find any options to make it non-interactive.

Eg: 
$ ./webserver.sh start

Server is started (pid 16675)

Log files are located at: /opt/webserver/logs

<***need to press enter***>

$

Comment: Maybe you can show us the code of `webserver.sh`

Comment: didn't understand your question fully, bur try `cat <(echo "") | ./webserver.sh start`

Comment: @bansi: This can be simplified to `printf '\n' | ./webserver.sh start` (POSIX-compliant), or, using Bash syntax, the even simpler `./webserver.sh start <<<''`.

Comment: @mklement0 nice suggestion and a nicer answer. just typed in what came to mind. my *nix is getting bit rusty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's really **as simple as pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> once per script invoked**, all you need to do is to send a newline via stdin; e.g.:

Contents of `testScript`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -p 'Press Enter to continue: '

echo 'Continuing...'
```

Invoking `testScript` with an automatic answer to the prompt:

```
testScript <<<''
```

You should see output `Continuing...` - `<<<''` simply sends a `\n` to `testScript`'s stdin (using a here-string, which automatically terminates the input string with `\n`, and therefore effectively sends `\n` here), which answers the prompt.

Applied to your sample command, we get:

```
./webserver.sh start <<<''
```

(Here-strings (`<<<`) are a nonstandard Bash extension (also supported by Ksh and Zsh); the POSIX-compliant alternative is:

```
printf '\n' | ./webserver.sh start
```

)

---

For **more complex interactions, use the [`expect` utility](http://expect.sourceforge.net/)**, which uses a (TCL-based) scripting language to simulate interactions with interactive scripts.

- `expect` is *not* preinstalled on most Linux platforms, but the respective package managers likely offer it; e.g., on Debian-based platforms such as Ubuntu, run `sudo apt-get expect` to install it.
- OS X, by contrast, *does* come with `expect` preinstalled.

Answer (score 0):

`yes` command may be the one you need. Please `man yes` to see more detail.

Or you just want to `echo -ne '\n' | <your command>`. Such as `echo -ne '\n' | webserver.sh start`

Comment: Tested with this option too and its working. thank you

Comment: @Kavin please vote up if it's working so other people reading this question might know

Comment: Sorry I dont have 15 reputation so I am not allowed  to vote now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping the bash script(s) inside an expect script.

Some basic examples here.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/